# OpenGL, How to use dynamic struct array in glsl with Shader Storage Buffer Object

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, shader, shader-storage-buffer

This is fragment shader which is using SSBO

```
struct Light
{
    float range;
    vec4 position;  
    vec4 color;
};

layout (std430) buffer LocalLights
{
    uint activeLightCount;
    Light light[];
} localLights;

void main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < localLights.activeLightCount; ++i)
    { //~~~~ doing lighting calc ~~~~/}
}
```

And this is the C++ data code for SSBO

```
struct Light
{
    float range;
    glm::vec4 position;
    glm::vec4 color;
};

struct LocalLightData
{
    unsigned int count;
    std::vector<Light> lights;
};
```

And this is Initialize C++ code (when Initialize, count is zero and lights vector is empty)
+) data variable is the type of LocalLightData

```
unsigned int index = glGetProgramResourceIndex(shader->programId, GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK, "LocalLights");

glGenBuffers(1, &ssbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo);
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int) + sizeof(Light) * data.lights.size(), &data, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, index, ssbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0);
```

And this is Update function (for updating dynamic size and data of vector)

```
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo);
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int) + sizeof(Light) * data.lights.size(), &data, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
glBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(unsigned int), &data.count);
glBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int), sizeof(Light) * data.lights.size(), data.lights.data());
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0);
```

I tired to use this code for updating dynamic size of lights, but it is not works.

For detail, the activeLightCount variable is working on shader, but Light light[] is not working.

What is the problem of my code? How can I fix this problem?

Use SSBO for making dynamic size of lights.

I want to fix the problem of my code.

Comment: Your problem isn't the dynamic size, but how padding (especially of vec3) works in a std430 layout. The c++ struct currently doesn't match the memory that is required by the SSBO interface block. Basically, vec3 is always padded to a vec4, but you need to read up on all the constraints a std430 layout imposes

Comment: The duplicate I linked takes about std140 layout, but since std430 doesn't change the way how vec3 are handled, it should give you some answers on the alignment problems.

Comment: @BDL
I changed to layout(std140).
Even if  I changed it the 
"glBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(unsigned int) + sizeof(Light) * data.lights.size(), &data);"
is not working.

After calling this line I called glGetError function.
the return value is INVAID_VALUE.

What is the problem of my code?

Comment: Did you read the post? I didn't say that you should use std140, I told you that no matter if you use std140 or std430, a vec3 needs very careful handling since they are aligned to the size of a vec4 (16byte). The duplicate explains that you can't create a C++ struct that satisfies this alignment and that you should not use vec3 in SSBO interface blocks at all.

Comment: The `LocalLightData` struct is no directly copyable. If you do that, you copy the count and the vector object itself, but not the data stored in the vector. You probably need to do something like `glBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(unsigned int), &data);` for the count and then `glBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int), sizeof(Light) * data.lights.size(), data.lights.data());`

Comment: That point I already also tried :( .
But same problem occurs.
After calling  glBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int), sizeof(Light) * data.lights.size(), data.lights.data()); the glGetError return INVALID_VALUE

Comment: INVALID_VALUE from glBufferSubData happens in one of three cases: offset is negative, size is negative, offset + size is larger than the allocated size of the buffer. I guess it is the third reason in your case. How large do you allocate the buffer?

Comment: Oh umm...
I called glBufferData function only Initialize time.
Should I call this function in Update?

Comment: Depends. As long as you don't increase the number of lights, it should be fine. When you increase the number of lights, you also need to allocate more memory for the buffer which means calling glBufferData again.

Comment: @BDL
I checked the values using RenderDoc (OpenGL debug tools) the value is not correctly conveying to shader :(

Comment: Even If I called glBufferData when I changed lights size, the activeLightCount works correctly. But lights information which includes range, position, color is not working correctly.
This means that these values are not conveying correctly and even if I updated lights count as 6, there information not saved all of it.

Comment: Could you update the question with the current code? I guess that there could still be a problem with the alignment in the Light struct. If I interpret alignment rule 9 *"If the member is a structure, the base alignment of the structure is N, where
N is the largest base alignment value of any of its members"* correctly, the range might also need to be padded to a vec4 (but not 100% sure).

Comment: Or you pack the range into one of the unused w coordinate of position or color. Alignments of c++ structs for buffers is always a mess when the structs members are of mixed types.

Comment: Updated!
And I am really thank you for tracking my issues!

Comment: I fixed!
Because of Light struct, the unsigned int value which is count also 16 bytes.
So I fixed the size like that :16 + sizeof(glm::vec4) * 3 * data.lights.size()
After doing like that, the code works correctly